# pandas 別のデータフレームにあるデータのみにフラグを付けたい

Tags: python, pandas

タイトルが分かりにくくて恐縮ですが、例えば以下の3個のデータフレームがあったとします。

・df_count
|日付|件数|
|2016-04-01|100|
|2016-04-02|1000|
|2016-04-03|300|
|2016-04-04|1500|

・df_CP1
|日付|キャンペーン名|
|2016-04-02|CP1|

・df_CP2
|日付|キャンペーン名|
|2016-04-04|CP2|

df_CP1やdf_CP2にデータがある日付のみに、それぞれのキャンペーンフラグが立つカラムを
df_countに追加したいのですが
良い方法はないでしょうか？

・df_count_2
|日付|件数|CP1フラグ|CP2フラグ|
|2016-04-01|100|0|0|
|2016-04-02|1000|1|0|
|2016-04-03|300|0|0|
|2016-04-04|1500|0|1|

※機械学習の元データにしたいと考えています。
df_countとdf_CP1をleft joinさせればできそうな気がしたのですが、
機械学習の元データにするためにはフラグ化が必要だと思い、フラグ化をするうまいやり方が思いつきませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df_CP1` と `df_CP2` データフレームの`キャンペーン名`カラムにある `CP1`, `CP2` を `1` に置き換えてから `left join` を行って、`NaN` 値を `0` に置換するという方法があります。

```
import pandas as pd

df_count_2 = pd.merge(
  pd.merge(
    df_count,
    df_CP1.rename(columns={'キャンペーン名': 'CP1フラグ'})
          .replace({'CP1フラグ': {'CP1': 1}}), on='日付', how='left'
  ),
  df_CP2.rename(columns={'キャンペーン名': 'CP2フラグ'})
        .replace({'CP2フラグ': {'CP2': 1}}), on='日付', how='left'
).fillna(0)
```

ただ、`df_CP1` と `df_CP2` データフレームに `キャンペーン名` カラムを含めなくてもよいとは思いますが、、

**追記**

`キャンペーン名`カラムを使わない場合(日付のみ)は以下の様になります。

```
import pandas as pd

# Clone
df_count_2 = df_count.copy()

# Add columns and initialize
df_count_2['CP1フラグ'] = 0
df_count_2['CP2フラグ'] = 0

# Select and update
df_count_2.loc[df_count_2['日付'].isin(df_CP1['日付']), 'CP1フラグ'] = 1
df_count_2.loc[df_count_2['日付'].isin(df_CP2['日付']), 'CP2フラグ'] = 1
```

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございました。　　
キャンペーン名カラムは無しにできたので、追記で頂いた内容でできました。　　
少し変更して、マージした後にフラグの欠損値を0で埋めるやり方でもできました。(フラグの0を最初に入れるか後で入れるかの違いだけですが)　　
　　
#キャンペーンデータフレームにフラグ列を追加　　
df_CP1['CP1フラグ'] = 1　　
　　
#df_countにキャンペーンデータフレームをleft join　　
df_count_2 = pd.merge(df_count, df_CP1, on=['日付'],how='left')　　
　　
#フラグの欠損値を0にする　　
df_count_2['CP1フラグ'].fillna(0, inplace=True)